# Chrome icon not appearing in Launcher

Tags: 11.04, unity, 64-bit, google-chrome, icons

I've been using Chromium for some time now, but I decided to switch over to Chrome. More features.
Anyways, I found that when I launch Chrome, its icon doesn't appear in the Launcher.

Do any of you have this problem, or is it just me?

I'm running x86_64 version of Natty and Chrome 14.0.797.0 dev build.

Comment: Is there a placeholder for the icon or a generic icon instead of the Chrome icon?  Or is there no indication at all in the launcher that Chrome is running?

Comment: No indication at all

Comment: I have a similar problem, but the Chrome icon is a blank space. When you click on it Chrome opens. Running X86-32bit

Comment: Does it happen after a restart as well? It once happened to me but has never happened again after i restarted

Comment: +1 - this is a common thing that I've yet to figure out what's going on. I haven't been able to describe it in a bug report easily either.

Comment: I wonder which "features" Chrome has that Chromium doesn't. Chromium is the base for Chrome, the only difference I know are Google trademarks, logos and icons. And Chromium is a carefully well packaged software, while Chrome installs are full of headaches and issues, like this one. I wonder why people still care about Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem a long time ago.
Sorry for not posting the solution.

Anyways, just add the icon to the launcher, then log off and log back in. It should work after that.

That's the only workaround I have.