# Why I can't see chrome in Dash

Tags: google-chrome, unity-dash, panel, icons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Chrome icon not appearing in Launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50781/chrome-icon-not-appearing-in-launcher)

I have installed Google Chrome and its works good. **BUT** I can't see it in panel
[image]

What is the problem?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/50781/chrome-icon-not-appearing-in-launcher

Comment: I just restart computer and all is OK